# How to get all assets of a certain addresss using SQL on Cexplorer

Tags: nft, cardano-db-sync, address, token

It seems like a simple question, but I was struggling to find the answer.

I am trying to get information of Cardano blockchain from cexplorer database.

Given an address such as 'addr1w9742z4fewans7ry6cjp95pc4ecv7y54cx298lp5qfw7s9gv8ukrj'
How can I get all the assets currently belonging to this address.
(the assets are minted tokens, nfts, amount of ADA, etc)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

For ADA balance, you can use the `utxo_view` table like this:

```sql
select * from utxo_view where
  address = 'addr1w9742z4fewans7ry6cjp95pc4ecv7y54cx298lp5qfw7s9gv8ukrj' ;
```

If you look at how `utxo_view` is defined, you can probably copy and tweak it so you are looking at the relevant multi_asset tables instead.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I understand that the utxo_view is for querying the number of ADA. But I still do not get how to get other assets. Could you please provide a rough idea of how to get other assets?

Comment: You will need to create a new SQL view (call it say `ma_utxo_view`) that uses the multi asset tables rather than the main tables.

Comment: I guess something like this, right?

```select multi_asset.name::text, ma_tx_out.*, tx_out.*
from public.multi_asset, public.tx_out, public.ma_tx_out
where multi_asset.id = ma_tx_out.ident and tx_out.id =  ma_tx_out.tx_out_id and
tx_out.address ='addr1w9742z4fewans7ry6cjp95pc4ecv7y54cx298lp5qfw7s9gv8ukrj'```

Comment: That seems correct, but I would suggest that you create a view (ie something like the `utxo_view`) and submit that via GH so I can add that as to the default `db-sync` distribution.